# Google Cloud TTS python script goes in deadlock without any particolar reason

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I was trying to use Google Cloud TTS API for a project of mine, and even fulfilling all dependencies and installing all the libraries and wrappers needed, i still encounter major problems that i dont understand.

Code Is here:

```
def synthesize_text(text):
    """Synthesizes speech from the input string of text."""
    from google.cloud import texttospeech
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

    input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)

    # Note: the voice can also be specified by name.
    # Names of voices can be retrieved with client.list_voices().
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code='en-US',
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)
    print("i'm here")
    response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)
    print("now, i'm here")
    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

At line 17 = "response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)" the process just stops executing without calling any exception and goes in deadlock.
I even tried to place two print before and after said instruction but only the first one gets executed.

I have used this guide: [google cloud guide](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python)

Can anybody help?

--Update
For no particular reason, now it works.. (maybe it was a connection problem to google servers)

Comment: Did you try "hello, world!" as `text`?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed :/

Comment: Can you hit ctrl + c and paste the KeyboardInterrupt traceback?

Comment: For no particular reason, now it works.. (maybe it was a connection problem to google servers)